# How to select dichotomous variables?

Tags: feature-selection, binary-data, factor-analysis, cohens-kappa, mcnemar-test

I have a data set of 57 dichotomous items that constitute a scale for measuring a particular condition. I also have another dichotomous variable of the condition itself. I would like to do some factor analysis and other analyses, but according to my power calculations the sample is too small, so I'd like to select the 20 most important items to include in further analysis. My question about is how to best do this.

Aside from theoretical considerations, I have been thinking about comparing the variables with respect to Cohen's kappa or the McNemar chi squared statistic, and select the 20 items with best statistic (highest for Cohen's kappa and lowest for McNemar chi squared). However, the two methods give quite different results, and the correlation between those statistics in my sample is only about -0.48.

Does anyone have suggestions about how to proceed with this issue?

Comment: How many data do you have?  What is the point, do you want the scale you construct from the 57 items to predict the other dichotomous variable? If you're making a scale, the 57 will become 1, so why do you have too many items?

Comment: I have a bit over 200 individuals in the study. I don't want to use scale, but I'd like to run factor analysis of the items among other things in order to understand more about the construct that the scale is supposed to measure. Obviously, it would be ideal with a much larger sample size so that I wouldn't have to select a subset of items.